# What are some terms of endearment for a girlfriend/wife?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

What are some Spanish terms of enderment you could use for a girlfriend or a wife?  In English I'm thinking things like sweetheart, sweetie, darling, cutie, babe, etc..

Any others that are unique to Spanish?

Comment: This question seems to be asking for a list of answers, which makes selecting a single "correct" answer very difficult. For this reason I am voting to close. If you can ask a more specific question ("What should I call my wife in XYZ situation?") that would probably be much more answerable and suitable for an SE site.

Comment: "Mon petit chou", for those who speak both Spanish and French.  (And English, if they can read this comment.)  ... Oh wait.. *unique* to Spanish... gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the standard ones like: amor, querida, princesa, cielita, guapa.

There are also others like gordita and bichita.

Comment: "Cariño" is the most common in Spain.